# Three.js TAA with MeshStandardMaterial

Tags: three.js

In order to get anti-aliasing working when my camera is not moving I tried to get TAA to work in my project. Example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_taa.

But it seems like it's not working as expected when using MeshStandardMaterial and a dimmer ambient light. The colors change.

This is how the example looks when I change the material to MeshStandardMaterial and add a light:
[left moving / right accumulated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9MQg.jpg).

Is there a way around this? Or which AA technique is best for this?